# How use Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter without tied it to the UI?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, messagingcenter

I have a long running task that need to be notified to the user using Toast-like messages. However, the user could move around the app freely.

Looking at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/, it show that is necessary to bind to the UI to it to work?

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "Hi", (sender) => {
    // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
});
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "Hi")
```

I need to send notifications in the background, and I don't know from there to who.

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe to the message in your `App.xaml.cs` (or `App.cs`) class. Then just send the message from where ever and the subscriber's delegate will be run.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look it does not need to be bound to the UI but just to an Object which is the subscriber. so you could just get away with setting the subscriber to 'this' in code.

To Recieve something you could use this without the .

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe(this, "Hi", (sender) => 
{
    // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
});
```

To send something you could use this.

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "Hi")
```

Comment: Bus is send the problem. In the background task I can't couple it to the form

Comment: What form do you mean? you can just set the subscriber to an object of the class itself?

Comment: Man they told you it "does not need to be bound to the UI", spread your wings and fly :)